# SpringBoot: ApplicationContext failed to load

Tags: java, spring-boot

Been at it for days, unable to figure out how to get around this issue with my spring boot tests. I've tried many different solutions here and tried to understand how tests work on SpringBoot, but I haven't had any luck and I've made myself more confused honestly.

```
2023-06-14 03:31:21.256  INFO 7691 --- [           main] c.a.underwritermicroservice.SmokeTest    : Starting SmokeTest using Java 17.0.7 on ip-172-31-84-196 with PID 7691 (started by ubuntu in /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/Sam/underwriter-microservice-pipeline/underwriter-microservice)
2023-06-14 03:31:21.256  INFO 7691 --- [           main] c.a.underwritermicroservice.SmokeTest    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-06-14 03:31:21.264  WARN 7691 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'smokeTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'application'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.aline.underwritermicroservice.UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2023-06-14 03:31:21.267 ERROR 7691 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field application in com.aline.underwritermicroservice.SmokeTest required a bean of type 'com.aline.underwritermicroservice.UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.aline.underwritermicroservice.UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication' in your configuration.
```

SmokeTest.java

```java
package com.aline.underwritermicroservice;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import com.aline.underwritermicroservice.controller.ApplicantController;
import com.aline.underwritermicroservice.controller.RootController;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.SpringVersion;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest(classes = SmokeTest.class)
class SmokeTest {

    @Autowired
    UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication application;

    @Autowired
    RootController rootController;

    @Autowired
    ApplicantController applicantController;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(application);
        assertNotNull(rootController);
        assertNotNull(applicantController);
    }

    @Test
    void usingCorrectVersions() {
        assertNotNull(SpringVersion.getVersion());
        assertTrue(SpringVersion.getVersion().startsWith("5"));
    }

}
```

UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication.java

```java
package com.aline.underwritermicroservice;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import com.aline.core.annotation.EnableCoreModule;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCoreModule
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.aline.underwritermicroservice")
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(
    title = "Underwriter Microservice API",
    description = "This API provides operations to either accept or deny an application for an account as well as Applicant and Member creation and management.",
    version = "1.0"
))
public class UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UnderwriterMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aline</groupId>
    <artifactId>aline-underwriter-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>underwriter-microservice</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0.2155</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.8</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>coverage</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@SpringBootTest(classes = SmokeTest.class)` with `@SpringBootTest`.

The `classes` parameter is not used correctly. It should be used to define the component classes to use for loading an `ApplicationContext` and if it's not defined whole context is loaded, referring to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html).